# What is the better practice when defining a collection field for Request object in Java?

Tags: java, json, interface, request, jackson

I am trying to figure out which way is a better way when defining a request object in Java. Assume we have following two Requests:

```
// use array for booksNames
class RequestA {
   private String requestId;
   private String[] booksNames;
}

// use set for booksNames
class RequestB {
   private String requestId;
   private Set<String> booksNames;
}
```

So basically, I am not sure which is better here, assume `booksNames` must be a collection of unique values, then why not use `Set` here. I am reading our codebase, and see folks are using array for such kind of fields, which confused me. (I cannot find those guys because they have all left the company, so I am asking here)

And BTW, we are using Jackson object mapper to mapping Java Request object to the Json strings. Maybe this is the reason?

Thanks in advance for helping out, I already spent a few hours on this simple question, hope I can get some insights from somebody here.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON array` can be mapped in `Java` to: `array`, `java.util.List` or `java.util.Set`. [Documentation](https://json.org/) says about array:

> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an
>   array, vector, list, or sequence.

Most natural is mapping it in `Java` to an array. It keeps an order and is straightforward. When you want to use `java.util.List` or `java.util.Set` you need to know which implementation is used by default and what is a side effect of it.

In case of `java.util.Set` you need to remember that order can be changed. So, if it is important - `Set` is a bad option.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = "[\"B\",\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"A\",\"B\"]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // array
    String[] array = mapper.readValue(json, String[].class);
    System.out.println(array.getClass().getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(array));

    // list
    List<String> list = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
    System.out.println(list.getClass().getName() + ": " + list);

    // set
    Set<String> set = mapper.readValue(json, Set.class);
    System.out.println(set.getClass().getName() + ": " + set);
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;: [B, A, B, C, A, B]
java.util.ArrayList: [B, A, B, C, A, B]
java.util.HashSet: [A, B, C]
```

As, you can see `String[]` and `java.util.ArrayList` shows the same result because `java.util.ArrayList` uses array behind the scene. When you use `Set` output does not keep order and removes duplicates.

In case, you need to validate request and check whether client sends duplicates or not you can not do that with default `Set` mapping. Also, memory footprint is bigger for `Set` than for an array.

Answer (score 0):

> we are using Jackson object mapper to mapping Java Request object to
>   the Json strings. Maybe this is the reason?

That can't be the reason as Jackson handles Set/List as well.

One possible reasoning to use Array/List Vs Set is, let's say you want to validate the request and let the consumer know that they sent duplicate Bookname (through an HTTP 400) instead of silently sanitizing the data and proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Which is better might depend on the usage of `booksNames` elsewhere in the code. The differences between array and some collection type is mainly that a collection type can not hold primitive values like `int` but requires object type like boxed `Integer`.

Of course there might be some memory & performance benefit when using array but this  does not usually play a big role. An `Array` can hold duplicates but so can a `List` also. See [this](https://javabydeveloper.com/arrays-vs-collections-java/) for more details.

The reasoning can be anything but it could be valid for example if `booksNames` is existing as an array everywhere else in the code. Why would it then be converted to a `Set` just before serializing?

On the other hand if it was - say - an array type here and a collection type there I would first consider things - like you mentioned - can there be duplicates (and if you do not know ask the people that make/accept the specifications) and refactor the code to pass only the collection type that you decide to use. It is just much more fun with collections (and Streams, not calling Arrays.asList() all the time).

**Note**: with the latter - to which I should add IMHO - I mean cases where `booksNames` is converted back and forth - from array to collection to array. If some class / method uses an array in its - maybe complex logic - it woould be easy to do by overriding (or overwriting) constructor/method to accept a collection type instead of an array and make it just convert teh collection type to an array as its first job.

Answer (score -1):

use the second one because you don't need to worry about the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :) BTW, you can use json object for second approach also, like this:
[image]